# Getting the Volume Level of A MediaPlayer object in android

Tags: java, android, media-player, volume

Ive been scouring the net for an aswer to this.

My app is a sort of soundboard that allows users to mix different loops together. So far ive got everything else working except for a very irritating part.

When a user long clicks a button i want to show a seekbar and then adjust the volume of the MediaPlayer to whatever progress level the seekbar is shifted to. i also want to set the progress bar to whatever volume level the MediaPlayer is at.

Problem is I cannot find a way to find the volume level of a particular MediaPlayer. I know there is a way to set the system volume using an Audio Manager but that isnt useful for mixing different sounds.

Any and all help is appreciated as I'm getting ready to tear my hair out.

Comment: You want to get the current media volume level right?

Comment: In MediaPlayer, there is a setVolume method to set the respective scalar values. You can find more information at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume%28float,%20float%29 Is this something you were looking for?

Comment: @Ganesh - Its true there is a set Volume method for the MediaPlayer class obbjects . However it seems to do absolutely nothing to the channel volume when modified. Will let you know if I figure out a way to fix this.I'm considering writing my own mixer now.